# Custom NSView Event Handelling

Tags: objective-c, macos, event-handling, interface-builder, nsview

I am trying to set up an interface like the one used in Xcodes interface builder.

What i would like to know is what i would need to do to translate mouse events i.e click drag & relay mouse position to the views position.

or double click events inside views trigger methods etc

Thank you in advance.

edit: for clarity

[interface builder http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/5269/screenshot20110824at204.jpg](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/5269/screenshot20110824at204.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a point in window coordinates, you can do `[view convertPoint:location fromView:nil]`. NSView has [similar methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW25) for rects and sizes.

Comment: Found it thank you so much thats perfect, how did I overlook the Event Handling methods. Have a lovely day.